# What are these strings called? What is squish? Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found this code:

```
sql = <<-SQL.squish
        UPDATE #{klass.constantize.table_name}
           SET uuid = uuid_generate_v4(), updated_at = now()
         WHERE id IN (#{group.map(&:id).join(',')})
           AND uuid IS NULL
      SQL
```

What is going on here? I assume this is some special kind of string delimiter. What is it called? Is it Ruby specific? What is `squish` doing?

Comment: See [this](http://apidock.com/rails/String/squish) for squish, about the way that's implemented, and the hardcoded table name used in the query, I don't believe is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 24):

This is a syntax for a [Here Document](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents) (`HereDoc`), which is a multiline string in Ruby.

For example, this:

```
sql = <<-SQL
        UPDATE #{klass.constantize.table_name}
           SET uuid = uuid_generate_v4(), updated_at = now()
         WHERE id IN (#{group.map(&:id).join(',')})
           AND uuid IS NULL
      SQL
```

Will give you an `sql` string variable whose value is literally:

```
         UPDATE #{klass.constantize.table_name}
           SET uuid = uuid_generate_v4(), updated_at = now()
         WHERE id IN (#{group.map(&:id).join(',')})
           AND uuid IS NULL
```

with all the spaces and newlines preserved.

From the HereDoc docs:

> To call a method on a heredoc place it after the opening identifier

A popular usage of that quote is when you have a long string and you don't want to write it on a single line, and hence use a HereDoc for it, but you still don't want to keep all the newline characters and white spaces that the HereDoc preserves, in which case you can just call [`squish`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/squish) (which is a method added by Rails) to remove them. For example, this:

```
sql = <<-SQL.squish
        UPDATE #{klass.constantize.table_name}
           SET uuid = uuid_generate_v4(), updated_at = now()
         WHERE id IN (#{group.map(&:id).join(',')})
           AND uuid IS NULL
      SQL
```

Will give you an `sql` string variable whose value is literally:

```
UPDATE #{klass.constantize.table_name} SET uuid = uuid_generate_v4(), updated_at = now() WHERE id IN (#{group.map(&:id).join(',')}) AND uuid IS NULL
```

With all consequent newline characters and spaces squished into one whitespace.

Comment: That's what  most confusing. Adding the method to the second delimiter would have made more sense IMHO. It raises a SyntaxError though, because it's looking for `SQL` and finds `SQL.squish`. It's kinda weird it works one way but not another.

Comment: @EricDuminil exactly, that's the point of adding the method call to the opening identifier instead of the closing one.

Comment: But it doesn't make much sense : why shouldn't it look for `SQL.squish` and complain that it can only find `SQL`?

Comment: @EricDuminil I'm not quite sure, maybe you should ask Matz :D but could be because a HereDoc identifier looks like a variable name, which cannot include a dot. So Ruby will understand that `SQL` is the identifier and can treat the part after the dot as method calls. However if you want to place the method call after the ending identifier, how would ruby know that `SQL.squish` is actually the closing identifier and not just part of the text itself?

Comment: I think you're not allowed to write `SQL` anywhere in the text anyway.

Comment: @EricDuminil: You can use it inside the string AFAIK. The delimiter is only recognized at the beginning of a line.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Thanks. Do you happen to know why it's not possible to call a method on the closing delimiter?

Comment: Probably because the original `SQL` is getting replaced by all the content beginning on the next line until the delimiter, and then squish is being called in the replacement. If it was on the closing delimiter it might just be ignored, or interpreted as the next block

Comment: @TamerShlash @EricDuminil it recognises the `SQL` is a heredoc delimiter not a variable name because it is immediately preceded by `<<-` The delmiter can  be anything as long as it starts with that e.g `<<-DESCRIPTION` then the content of the string starts on the next line and everything following is the content until it sees a line with the delmiter on it's own with nothing else on that line (that's why the method call can't be on the last delimiter, but can be on the first, since the content doesn't start until the line after the first delimiter)

Answer (score 6):

`String#squish` comes from Rails and means that resulting inline string is without multiple `\n` and `\s`.
From [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/String/squish):

> Returns the string, first removing all whitespace on both ends of the
>   string, and then changing remaining consecutive whitespace groups into
>   one space each.